# 301 Redirect .HTACCESS by ends of urls

Tags: .htaccess

I have some urls

```
domain.com/bla-bla-bla-2/
domain.com/cvb-sdffgh-ffdds-2/
domain.com/ssss-asdfgh-fdsaxcv-2/
domain.com/fgh-fgh-fgh-3/
domain.com/dcv-qwe-vbn-4/
domain.com/dcv-qwe-vbn-2020/
domain.com/dcv-qwe-vbn-99/
domain.com/dcv-qwe-vbn-9/
```

I need to make a 301 redirect to new URLs that do not have ONE number at the end

```
domain.com/bla-bla-bla/
domain.com/cvb-sdffgh-ffdds/
domain.com/ssss-asdfgh-fdsaxcv/
domain.com/fgh-fgh-fgh/
domain.com/dcv-qwe-vbn/
domain.com/dcv-qwe-vbn-2020/
domain.com/dcv-qwe-vbn-99/
domain.com/dcv-qwe-vbn/
```

Please help with this!

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)-(\d+))/ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When you configure this in .htaccess, then the path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a slash, that has been stripped off already at this point.

Comment: Plus you got an unmatched `)` in your pattern.

Comment: And you did not anchor the pattern at the end, which you might want to do (if you _don't_ want to match a URL path such as `/cvb-sdffgh-ffdds-2/foo` as well here.)

Comment: Why are `/dcv-qwe-vbn-2020/` and `/dcv-qwe-vbn-99/` handled differently to the other URLs?

Answer (score 0):

This will match only urls that have one number at the end :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)-(\d?)/$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```